# Serenity report shows 0 tests run with JUnit 5 and Cucumber 7

Tags: cucumber, junit5, serenity-bdd, serenity

I am trying to convert a Java test project from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. I'm using Cucumber 7 for running some dummy feature files and Serenity for generating fancy reports.
Using JUnit 4 everything worked fine. After I finally adjusted my runner, dependencies and other configs to work with JUnit 5, now the Serenity Report shows 0 tests run (and they are running correctly).
Is there something wrong with my config or are there any conflicts between Serenity and JUnit that I am missing here?

My POM:

```
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.76</bouncycastle.version>
        <log4j.version>2.20.0</log4j.version>
        <json.version>20230618</json.version>
        <rest-assured.version>5.3.2</rest-assured.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.10.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.10.0</junit-platform.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.14.0</cucumber.version>
        <serenity.version>4.0.18</serenity.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <failsafe-plugin.version>3.1.2</failsafe-plugin.version>
        <serenity-plugin.version>3.9.7</serenity-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
            <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-reports</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <filters>
            <filter>src/test/resources/filters/filter_${env}.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>CucumberRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check-gherkin</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check-gherkin</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>LOCAL</id>
            <properties>
                <env>LOCAL</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <properties>
                <env>DEV</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>QA</id>
            <properties>
                <env>QA</env>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

My runner class:

```
package runners;

import net.serenitybdd.junit5.SerenityJUnit5Extension;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.OBJECT_FACTORY_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("TEST EXAMPLE")
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@ExtendWith(SerenityJUnit5Extension.class)
@SelectPackages({"steps", "environment"})
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = OBJECT_FACTORY_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.picocontainer.PicoFactory")
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

The last lines of the Maven output when I run "mvn clean verify":

```
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.740 s -- in runners.CucumberRunner
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- serenity-maven-plugin:3.9.7:aggregate (serenity-reports) @ api-regression-test-automation-poc ---
[INFO] GENERATING REPORTS USING 16 THREADS
[INFO] GENERATING SUMMARY REPORTS...
[INFO] GENERATING REQUIREMENTS REPORTS...
[INFO] GENERATING RESULT REPORTS...
[INFO] GENERATING ERROR REPORTS...
[INFO] Test results for 0 tests generated in 2.7 secs in directory: file:/<my-project-path-here>/reports/serenity/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.500 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-02T12:50:14-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The report:

[image: Serenity Report]

I have been looking for the root cause of this problem on the internet and so far haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this annotation to the `Runner` class.

```
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME,value = "io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporterParallel,pretty,timeline:target/test-results/timeline")
```

Comment: Wow, this worked! I can now see the report being generated correctly. Thank you!